# divide array into subarrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void update(char array[]){
int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS;i++){
    char *subarray = array+(SUBARRAY_SIZE*i);
        for(j = 0;j<SUBARRAY_SIZE;j++){ 
            subarray[j]='d';
        }
    //print_array(subarray);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** divide array into `NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS` and make them all change the original array with "`d`"s in a single process program (...then in a multi-process program and compare the results)

So, this is my first attempt to solve this in a single process program. if I do it like this, isn't it really inefficient since every sub-array is longer than enough?

For example,

```
ARRAY_SIZE=10

NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS=2
```

now, every sub-array has 10 elements but 2 was enough actually. Isn't it a problem considering the desired `ARRAY_SIZE` is 5M? if it is, what should I do? I am kind of lost here, so I'd appreciate if you could briefly explain this to me.

Comment: "*now, every subarray*" you did not even defined *one* array in the code you show. All I see is pointers.

Comment: yeah, exactly! i guess i was confused about arrays and pointers. all i'm doing here is moving a pointer around, right? i am not actually defining any sub-arrays. riiight, cheers. is this a valid solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you meant `SUBARRAY_SIZE` instead of `ARRAY_SIZE`.

You mean 2 is *enough* in your opinion because there is only `d` and `\0` as distinct elements. Well, that is not the point of the exercise. It is probably more of working around with pointers arithmetic through *arrays*.

The idea is to divide the *array* as putting the terminating character where it's needed and the just initialize it. That is exactly what you are missing in your attempt.

Here is one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS 2
#define SUBARRAY_SIZE 10

void update(char array[])
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS; i++) {
        char *subarray = array + (SUBARRAY_SIZE*i);

        for(j = 0; j < SUBARRAY_SIZE; j++){ 
            subarray[j]='d';
        }
        subarray[SUBARRAY_SIZE] = '\0'; /* POINT OF THE EXERCISE */ 
        printf("%d. %s", i, subarray);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[21];

    update(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't terminate it, there is *no way* to be at least later printed out. The format specifier `s` in `printf` searches exactly `\0` to stop. Keep in mind that when it is not declared as array, you would need to allocate memory dynamically for pointer and then **check** it. In the case of `subarray`, no, because it uses the `array` address as base.